# How to get value from Multi Lookup field using SharePoint rest API call?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column, spfieldlookupvalue

I have one list with lookup column `#lookupColOne` and this value is used in `#list2`.

`#List2` have a lookup column of `#List1` ID field. I want to get `#list2` data along with `#list1` lookup column values.

Anyone suggest the idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your RESTful URL something like below:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<Display name of #List2>')/items?$select=Title,Country/ID,Country/Title&$expand=Country
```

Where,

1. `Country`: Lookup column in `#List2` which is referencing data in `#List1`.
2. `Country/ID` and `Country/Title`: Gives the ID and Title for selected Item from `#List1`.

**Note**:

If you are trying to get the lookup column data from two or more levels of lookup columns then it is not supported in SharePoint REST API. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612164/can-we-query-multi-level-lookup-columns-in-sharepoint-online-using-rest-api/56236843).

Answer (score 0):

following snippet should help you a lot. It expands data from List2 with the information from lookUp in List1

```
this.web.lists.getByTitle('LIST2NAME').items.select(['Column','Column/Id']).expand('Column').get().then(result => {
          return result 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using select and expand.

Here is the sample REST URL.

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items$select=ColumnNamein#list2/ColumnNamein#list1&$expand=ColumnNamein#list2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the IMMEDIATE lookup values in rest api. The workaround would be to extend your 2nd lookup in list1 and get all the values you want (which will be added to list1 as text fields). You can get these values using Rest on lookup of list2